# Are .txt files only created after the process is terminated? Python

Tags: python, text-files

Maybe this is just how Python works but I think I'm missing something, I've looked around and I can't find anything addressing this.

Are text files only created after the process is terminated, or have I made a mistake?

Here's the code I'm using to generate the text file:

```
user_name_token = open("user_name_token.txt", "w")
```

If that is just how Python works and .txt files are only generated after the process is terminated, then there's no need to look at the code below. However, if I've made a mistake and that's why the .txt file is only generated after the process is terminated, please do let me know.

I've put what I feel to be the relevant code sequence below.

The following code, if the file exists, converts the text inside to a str value and leads to a greeting where the str value is used but it isn't relevant here. Instead, we'll carry on as if the file does not exist yet; and go to `initial_greeting_and_initial_user_name_set()` after `initialization()`:

```
initialization()

    def initialization():
        global user_name
        global initial_login_token
    
        if os.path.isfile("user_name_token.txt") == True:
    
            file = open("user_name_token.txt")
    
            user_name = file.read().replace("\n", " ")
    
            file.close
    
            print(user_name)
    
            time_based_greeting()
    
        else:
            initial_greeting_and_initial_user_name_set()
```

The following code allows the user to create the user name and leads to `initial_greeting_and_inital_user_name_set_token_generation()` when the button is pressed:

```
def initial_greeting_and_initial_user_name_set():
    global initial_greeting_label
    global initial_greeting_space0
    global user_name
    global initial_greeting_progression_button

    initial_greeting_label = Label(root, text="Hello! It's nice to meet you, my name is Eve, what's yours?")
    initial_greeting_space0 = Label(root, text=" ")
    user_name = Entry(root)
    initial_greeting_progression_button = Button(root,\
                                                 text="Enter",\
                                                 command=initial_greeting_and_initial_user_name_set_token_generation)

    initial_greeting_label.pack()
    initial_greeting_space0.pack()
    user_name.pack()
    initial_greeting_progression_button.pack()
```

The following code uses the user Entry to create a .txt file with the user name inside and loops back to `initialization()`:

```
def initial_greeting_and_initial_user_name_set_token_generation():
    global user_name_token

    user_name_token = open("user_name_token.txt", "w")

    user_name_token.write(user_name.get())

    initialization()
```

Thank you for any help, especially given it's a long read if I have in-fact made a mistake and that's why the .txt file is only created after the window is closed.

Again, if it's just normal for .txt files to only be generated after the process is terminated and not when the code to create it has been run; then there's no need to take the above code into account.

Comment: The file is probably created as soon as you open it, but writing may happen buffered. The buffer will be flushed when you close the file, which probably happens automatically when your program ends. You an use a `with` block or manually close the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear just what your code is doing as you're opening a file for writing and then opening it again for reading before you've closed it for writing.  You should close your file for writing before you go on to open it for reading:

```
def initial_greeting_and_initial_user_name_set_token_generation():
    global user_name_token

    user_name_token = open("user_name_token.txt", "w")

    user_name_token.write(user_name.get())

    user_name_token.close()

    initialization()
```

or better yet:

```
def initial_greeting_and_initial_user_name_set_token_generation():
    global user_name_token

    with open("user_name_token.txt", "w") as user_name_token:

        user_name_token.write(user_name.get())()

    initialization()
```

This latter construct is the preferred way to open a file such that you're sure it gets closed.  It will remain open only inside the `with` block and will then be closed automatically.

Python does not hold back any I/O operations.  Like other languages, it performs the operations right away.  It may buffer up write operations and write the results in larger blocks, but all writing is completed when you call `close()` on the file (or when the associated `with` block is exited, closing the file automatically).

Comment: Perfect fix, thank you. I also forgot '()' on a 'file.close' in 'initialization()' for anybody looking at this question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that's the problem, but in that code:

```
initialization()

def initialization():
    global user_name
    global initial_login_token

    if os.path.isfile("user_name_token.txt") == True:

        file = open("user_name_token.txt")

        user_name = file.read().replace("\n", " ")

        file.close

        print(user_name)

        time_based_greeting()

    else:
        initial_greeting_and_initial_user_name_set()
```

It seems to me like you forgot to call the file.close method.
Add brackets at the end, so it will look as follows:
`file.close()`.

Comment: Whilst this didn't fix the problem, it was something I needed to do not only in 'initialization()' but also in 'initial_greeting_and_initial_user_name_set_token_generation()' too. Thank you.